# Symfony: where should i put business logic in models?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Suppose I have this models

- User.class.php
- userTable.class.php

I want to create a method to update the user

Action

```
class userActions extends sfActions {

public function executeUpdateUser(sfWebRequest $request) {
     $user_id = $request->getParameter('id');
     // here i want to call function to update the user 
     // updateUser($id);
}
```

Where should I put this function `updateUser($id)` ?

ON `user.class.php` --> And call it like that `User::updateUser($id);`

OR ON `userTable.class.php` --> And call it like that `Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->updateUser($id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it this way :

```
$user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->find($user_id);
$user->updateWithData($data); // ::update() is already an existing method
$user->save();
```

or

```
$user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->find($user_id);
$user->updateWithDataAndSave($data);
```

Comment: If you want to perform one query, you should do it in `userTable.class.php` (your second example).

Comment: If everything was about speed and premature optimisation, you wouldn't be using Symfony :D That solution is more clean, practical, and the performance cost of that extra query is negligible, so  there's no problem for me.

Comment: @user1272589 second. `Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->updateUser($user_id);`

Comment: `$user = Doctrine::getTable('User')->updateUserByIdWithData($userId, $arr_data);`